# solve $\int x^{-c} \left( 1 + y(x)^2 \right)^{-\frac{a+1}{2}} dy$ where $e^y = x^c + bx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to make some progress on solving the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-c} \left( 1 + y(x)^2 \right)^{-\frac{a+1}{2}} dy$$
with $y(x)$ defined as
$$e^y = x^c + bx$$
for $a \in \mathbb{N}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $c \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

In the interesting parameter values (low $a$ and $c$), the integral seems to diverge to $+\infty$ at the left and sometimes also at the right tail. If the standard Riemann integral can not be taken, I wonder if there is other way of assigning some reasonable value to it.

My attempts so far:

1. I considered taking Cauchy Principal Value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), but as far as I understand it's not applicable to tail infinities of the same sign.
2. I considered methods of contour integration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration), but am not really familiar with them and not sure if they can help here.
3. I was also thinking about multiplying the function by some special integrator $\psi_\lambda(x)$ where $\lambda$ is some parameter, which would allow taking the integral analytically, and then $\lambda$ could be sent to some limiting value forcing it to vanish from the integral's computed value. But so far I could not come up with the multiplier that works.
4. Integrating or taking CPV numerically in Mathematica did not help.

I would appreciate all the suggestions, negative results with explanations would also help.

**Extra**:
An alternative way to write down this integral is substituting out $y$ (with the corresponding correction term):
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-c} \frac{cx^{c-1}+b}{x^c+bx} \left( 1 + (\ln(x^c+bx))^2 \right)^{-\frac{a+1}{2}} dx$$